# Show slider controlling all content once when returning map items in React

Tags: reactjs

I have some CMS content being returned and my goal is to have a year slider controlling the content depending on the year that the user selects by clicking the minus/plus arrow.

This is my code:

```
import "./styles.css";

import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DatesProvider>
        {data.map((item, index) => {
          const Slice = slices[item.type];
          return <Slice section={item.section} key={index} />;
        })}
      </DatesProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

const DateContext = React.createContext({});

const DatesProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [dates, setDates] = React.useState({});
  return (
    <DateContext.Provider value={{ dates, setDates }}>
      {children}
    </DateContext.Provider>
  );
};

const DatePicker = ({ section }) => {
  const { dates, setDates } = React.useContext(DateContext);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Set initial date
    setDates((prevDates) => {
      prevDates[section] = 2021;
      return { ...prevDates };
    });
    // Clean up on dismount
    return () => {
      setDates((prevDates) => {
        delete prevDates[section];
        return { ...prevDates };
      });
    };
  }, []);

  const handlePlus = () => {
    setDates((prevDates) => ({
      ...prevDates,
      [section]: prevDates[section] + 1
    }));
  };

  const handleMinus = () => {
    setDates((prevDates) => ({
      ...prevDates,
      [section]: prevDates[section] - 1
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
      <button onClick={handleMinus}>-</button>
      <span>{dates[section]}</span>
      <button onClick={handlePlus}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Item = ({ section }) => {
  const { dates } = React.useContext(DateContext);

  return (
    <div>
      Section: {section} | Year: {dates[section]}
    </div>
  );
};

const data = [
  { type: "DatePicker", section: "foo" },
  { type: "Item", section: "foo" },
  { type: "Item", section: "foo" },
  { type: "DatePicker", section: "bar" },
  { type: "Item", section: "bar" },
  { type: "Item", section: "bar" }
];

const slices = { DatePicker, Item };
```

The result is currently this:

[image]

As you can tell it's returning the year slider several times and the structure is similar to this:

```
<slider> - 2021 + </slider>
<section class= "container-of-all-items">
<all-items></all-items>
</section>
<slider> - 2021 + </slider>
<section class= "container-of-all-items">
<all-items></all-items>
</section>
```

My goal is to have only one year slider wrapping/controlling the whole content items rather than the above repetition of sliders:

```
<slider> - 2021 + </slider>
<section class= "container-of-all-items">
<all-items></all-items>
</section>
```

Any idea how to achieve it by maintaining a map through the `Slices`?

Comment: What is data on the first data.map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see, took me a while to understand, you basically want to have one set of + and - but list of items.

Then in your case, you code actually simplifies.

```
function Lists() {
  const { dates, setDates } = React.useContext(DateContext);
  const onClick = () => { setDates(...) }

  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={onClick}>+</div>
      <>
        {dates.map((item, index) => {
          return <Slice section={item.section} key={index} />
        })}
      </>
      <div>-</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then change your App.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DatesProvider value={...}>
         <Lists />
      </DatesProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Actually you might not need the context at all, since the logic has been promoted to the parent. But it's up to you.